# `len`とfor文からしか使われな引数には、どんな型ヒントを付けるべきか？

Tags: python

## 環境

Python3.9

## やりたいこと

文字列の集合体を受け取る関数を作りたいです。
関数内では、`len`と`for`文を使います。

`len`と`for`文しかないので、list以外の要素も受け取れるようにしたいです。
たとえば、以下の型はすべてサポートしたいです。

- list
- set
- numpy.ndarray

## 質問

この場合、引数にはどのような型ヒントを付けるべきでしょうか？
以下のように`Union`を使えば、複数の型を指定できますが、可読性があまりよろしくありません。

```
def foo(user_ids: Union[Set[str],List[str], numpy.ndarray]):
    print(f"length{len(user_ids)})
    for user_id in user_ids:
        print(user_id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/collections.abc.html

`__iter__`と`__len__`をサポートする[collections.abc.Collection](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Collection) でいいと思います。

```py
from collections.abc import Collection

def foo(user_ids: Collection[str]):
    ...
```